# White LED W/ 3V or less?

Tags: voltage, led, joule-thief

I'm designing a front end bike light just for the fun of it, and I've hit a problem. So far my design will have an input voltage of 3V, but all the white LEDs I find have a forward voltage of 3.2V or greater. I am curious if there are any white LEDs that I can run off of 3V.

My goal of this light is more of a "be seen" light than a "light up the entire area" light. I plan on blinking the LED with a 555 timer. I will power my circuit with 2 AAA batteries, or maybe a watch battery.

Comment: There seem to be many on Digikey....

Comment: Two AA alkaline batteries are 3V only for a few minutes when they are brand new.

Comment: LEDs that operate under 3v are available. || You  need better batteries. At least 4 X AAA zinc or alkaline. Better 1 X LiIon

Answer (score 13, accepted):

White LEDs are actually blue LEDs with a phosphor that converts some of the blue light into yellow light that mixes with the blue to form white.

The voltage of an LED is related to the energy of the photons in the light it produces and that energy is dependent on the color(wavelength).  To make Blue light requires about 3V. The longer wavelength of the light from other color LEDs, such as red or green results in them not requiring as much voltage, 1.4-2.6 depending upon the particular LED and color.

The voltage requirement for blue LEDs (used in a white LED) has been going down in recent years but won't ever reach much below 3V. The actual voltage of course also varies with the current, which dictates the brightness.

Since you are intending to power the circuit from a 2-cell alkaline battery although it may be slightly greater than 3V when new, it will drop as the battery runs down.  To get a good life out of the battery you should design your circuit to work with just 0.9V per cell, i.e. 1.8V for a 2 cell battery or 2.7V for 3-cell.

As Stefan suggests the best way is to use a switching power supply to convert the battery voltage to that needed by the LED.  Then you will get the best battery life.

This article from Maxim has some useful information regarding LEDs: [GUIDE TO LED CIRCUIT DESIGNS AND LED BASICS & OPERATION](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/3/3070.html)

Answer (score 6):

OK - you probably resolved this issue a couple of years ago, but another option you could have considered is to use a Joule Thief type circuit to boost the voltage - Solar charged Christmas lights can power entire strings of 100 or more white LEDs from a single AA 1.2v cell using this concept, and the components required are pretty simple... One resistor, a common transistor, and you can build the coil yourself.  Use the 2 AAA cells to power the 555, and then send the 555 pulses to the Joule Thief to power the LEDs.

Comment: To be honest, I had completely forgotten about this project! Thanks for the idea, I might use it soon

Comment: @Gigaxalus -- The proper ratio of input voltage to output voltage is 1 to 2.  So you can use a single AAA into a 3V LED (1.5V => 3V), or two AAA in series into two 3V LED's in series (3V=>6V). My favorite ratio is 4xAA into 4 LED's in series (6V => 12V).  Note that they do have 6V and higher voltage LED's in a single device package if you want a point light source.

Answer (score 4):

You could try a switching power supply to boost your voltage up to 3.2V - 3.3V.